# Strange pause when python download file from ftp

Tags: download, windows-server-2012-r2, ftplib

I have some code, where i check some directories on ftp server and download new files on my server. There are above 3 million files on server (zip archives). I am doing many not optimize things in this code, but all of them works fast, except part with downloading. Here is this part:

```
lf = open(local_filename, "wb") //here i create blank file
print ("opened")
try:
    ftp.retrbinary("RETR "+name, lf.write) //here i write data 
    print ("wrote")
except ftplib.error_perm:
    pass
lf.close() //here i close file with data
print ("closed")
```

my problem in the part between print ("opened") and print ("wrote"). My python console (2.7) keep silence for 10-20 second on this fase, but size of downloading files is very tiny. Its below 2-3 Kb.

Strange thing in next: when i start script from my own PC (windows 7), it works great and fast, but when i start it on windows server 2012 R2 (VDS), i got this sadly pause. Guys, i need your help. What should i do for configuration my server and fast downloading?

Answer (score 0):

i got the answer. just need to run next command:

netsh int tcp set global ecncapability=disabled

and everything will be excellent!